# Unable to find php7.3 on Ubuntu 19

Tags: php, ubuntu

I am not able to install php7.3 on my ubuntu 19.04. I am currently having php7.2

I ran commands in this orders :

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ondrej/php
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt install php7.3
```

But I am getting error

```
E: Unable to locate package php7.3
```

Comment: If you have `aptitude` you could search php7.3 like this `sudo aptitude search php | grep '7.3'`

Comment: did you try `sudo apt install php7.*`?